# Does it matter how many models are in a single namespace?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, namespaces

In an MVC app, does it matter how many models are in the `MyApp.Models` namespace?

I have just enough models to make it worthwhile splitting them into separate folders (e.g. /Models/Users, /Models/Emails, /Models/Messages, etc).

MVC by default gives new models a namespace corresponding to the folder structure (e.g. `MyApp.Models.Users`, `MyApp.Models.Emails`, `MyApp.Models.Messages`, etc).

It seems easier to me to have **all** models in the same namespace, simply `MyApp.Models`.

However I want to check that this isn't a daft move before going against this default MVC convention.

For example, does importing a namespace with 500 models inside it have any kind of overhead or disadvantages?

Comment: Aside from naming conflicts, there is no issue. Although, you may want to look for opportunities to refactor if you have that many models.

Comment: Cool, thank you.  I don't *think* I need to in this case.  Would you mean refactoring as in splitting into areas?

Comment: Refactoring could be splitting namespaces, such as into areas, sure. But also it could mean taking advantage of places where (just my assumption) the view model was trivial and didn't need an actual model. Perhaps you should consider sometimes simply using the underlying type, an enumerable of the type, a tuple, or a dictionary.

Comment: That makes sense, and very clearly explained, thank you. I think that qualifies as an answer if you'd care to make it one....

Comment: If have general design questions like this, you can always bring them to the [c# chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c) here at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Well I googled the hell out of this question and couldn't find any guidance.  So I figure it might be a useful question to have up.   That said, I've never used the chat rooms I should give it a try :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from naming conflicts, there is no issue. Although, you may want to look for opportunities to refactor if you have that many models.

Refactoring could mean splitting namespaces, such as into areas, but also it could mean taking advantage of places where (just my assumption) the view model was trivial and didn't need an actual model.

Perhaps you should consider sometimes simply using the underlying type, an enumerable of the type (as in a [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [Array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), or some other [Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybcx56wz.aspx)), a [Tuple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).